# How to find probability in case of 2 dimensional random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Let $(X, Y)$ be a 2D random variable such that $E(X)=E(Y)=3$ and variance of  both $X$ and $Y$ is $1$ . Covariance between $X$ and $Y$ is $1/2$. 
Then what is $P(|X-Y| >6)$?

I think chebyshev's inequality for multidimensional random variables can be applied, but I can't reach anywhere with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
P(|X-Y|>6)\leq\frac{ E(X-Y)^{2}}{6^2}.
$$
To compute $E(X-Y)^{2}$, observe that
$$
E(X-Y)^{2}=EX^2-2EXY+EY^2\tag{1}\label{1}.
$$
Also
$$
1=\text{Var}(X)=EX^2-(EX)^2=EX^2-3^2
$$
and similarly for $\text{Var}(Y)$. Lastly
$$
0.5=\text{Cov}(X,Y)=EXY-EX\cdot EY=EXY-9.
$$
You have everything to plug into $\eqref{1}$.